# Understanding SQL IN clause with NULL values

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-null

Assume the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE X (x_name VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE Y (y_name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO X VALUES ('blue');
INSERT INTO X VALUES ('red');
INSERT INTO Y VALUES ('blue');
```

Resulting in:

```
+---------+        +---------+
| Table X |        | Table Y |
+---------+        +---------+
|  x_name |        |  y_name |
+---------+        +---------+
|  'blue' |        |  'blue' |
|   'red' |        +---------+
+---------+
```

The results of the following queries are as expected:

- `SELECT * FROM X WHERE x_name IN (SELECT y_name FROM Y);` will return one row `| 'blue' |`.
- `SELECT * FROM X WHERE x_name NOT IN (SELECT y_name FROM Y);` will return one row `| 'red' |`.

Let's insert `NULL` into table Y:

```
INSERT INTO Y VALUES (NULL);
```

The first query will return the same result (`blue`). However, the second query from above will return no rows. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `not in` with subqueries.  Period.  Use `not exists`; it does what you want:

```
select x.*
from x
where not exists (select 1 from y where y.y_name = x.x_name);
```

The problem is this.  When you have:

```
x_name in ('a', 'b', null)
```

SQL actually returns `NULL`, not `false`.  However, `NULL` is treated the same as `false` in `where` clauses (and `when` clauses but not for `check` constraints).  So, the row gets filtered out.

When you negate this, either as:

```
not x_name in ('a', 'b', null)
x_name not in ('a', 'b', null)
```

The results is `not NULL` which is also `NULL` and everything gets filtered out.

Alas.  The simplest solution in my opinion is to get in the habit of using `not exists`.